# Client-side code to fix CORs issue when using fetch (without cors module)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, localhost

It searched and already included the typical backend code

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    //res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000/storeScore');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    //res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});
```

but I still get `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/storeScore. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).` followed by

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` I mean don't I have the header `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` ?

My frontend code is

```
function someFunction() {
            const sessionHighscore = cumulativeScore;
            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    //'Origin' : 'http://localhost:80',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(sessionHighscore)
            };

            fetch('http://localhost:3000/storeScore', options);
        }
```

Maybe I need to include something in client-side header? I think local html is hosted on port 80?

Notes:

- I am trying to send data from a local website to a mysql database on localhost:3000
- I am using express for backend, and trying Not to use cors module as solution
- Also is there any resources to show me how to execute routes without manually changing
  localhost? Like to use localHost:3000/createTable I have to type this manually into the url, can I do this with code?

Edit:

- Looking at network tab in my browser I found the OPTIONS request is successful but the POST after is missing the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header; I just need to know to how to ensure the POST also gets the header

Comment: It says "CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing" which suggests the backend code was set up wrong.

Comment: But `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` is literally there so what would you suggest is wrong with backend?

Answer (score -1):

On your fetch request, add useCredentials: true.

Comment: Why? They aren't sending any credentials.

Comment: aren't you supposed to set it to true on post requests with data in it? I could be wrong.

Comment: No, only on requests with credentials.

Answer (score -1):

Please install package npm i cors.

then apply middleware as:

require as

```
 const cors = require("cors");
```

middleware code

```
app.use(cors())
```